# jquery play and pause buttons to start/stop image plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

I have an image slider plugin that gets initialized onload with this:

```
                  $('#headerwrapper img').peTransitionHilight({
                           slideshow: true, 
                           transition: "all", 
                           duration: 1234, 
                           delay: 8888, 
                           boost: 0.6
                  });
```

Once started it runs forever.

I'm trying to figure out how to make it startable and stoppable, as in:

```
<button class="play">play</button>
<button class="pause">pause</button>
```

I've tried many approaches but nothing gives, e.g.,

```
var interval;
function slideBoxTimeout(){
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        slideBoxTransition();
    }, delay);  
}

$(".play").click(function() {
    slideBoxTimeout();
});
$(".pause").click(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

What's a good way to start and stop this thing?

The plugin itself -

```
(function($) {

$.pixelentity = $.pixelentity || {version: '1.0.0'};

$.pixelentity.hilight = {   
    conf: {
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
        transition: "vertbars",
        duration:1500,
        elements:30,
        maxSize:250,
        minSize:50,
        slideshow: false,
        images: [],
        links: [],
        linkTarget: false,
        delay: 3000,
        boost: 0,
        over:false,
        fallback: false
    } 
};

var cloneStyles = ["float","display","margin-top","margin-right","margin-bottom","margin-left","position","top","left"];
var transitionTypes=["vertbars","circles","horizbars","squares"];

function PeTransitionHilight(target, conf) {

    var self = this;
    var jthis = $(this);
    var inited = false;
    var parent;
    var w,h;
    var from,to;
    var output,buffer,buffer2,toBuffer,fromBuffer;
    var items,n;
    var offset,transition,duration,compositingDuration,started = 0,elapsed = 0;
    var fallback = false;
    var command = false;
    var loading = true;
    var images,slideshowTimer = 0, slideshowIndex = 1;
    var over;
    var mouseOver = false, active = false, firstRun = true;
    var transitionIdx=0;

    function start() {
        w = conf.width;
        h = conf.height;
        loading = true;
        images = conf.images;
        conf.boost = Math.min(1,parseFloat(conf.boost));
        $.pixelentity.preloader.load(target,targetLoaded);

    }

    function targetLoaded() {
        w = w || target.width();
        h = h || target.height();

        if (target[0].tagName.toLowerCase() == "img") {
            from = target;
        } else {
            from = target.find("img:eq(0)");
        }

        parent = $("<span>").width(w).height(h);

        var i=cloneStyles.length;
        while (i--) {
            parent.css(cloneStyles[i],target.css(cloneStyles[i]));
        }

        target.css({
            "position": "relative",
            "float": "none",
            "margin": 0,
            "top": 0,
            "left": 0
        });

        target.wrap(parent);
        parent = target.parent();

        if (conf.slideshow) {
            if (images.length === 0 && target.attr("data-destination")) {
                images =  target.attr("data-destination").split("|");
            }
            if (images.length > 0) {
                if (!conf.over) {
                    slideshowTimer = setInterval(slideshow,Math.max(conf.duration+200,conf.delay));
                }
            } else {
                conf.slideshow = false;
            }
        }

        var destination = false;
        if (!(conf.slideshow || conf.over)) {
            destination = getDestination();
        }

        loading = false;

        if (destination) {
            loadTo(destination);
        } else {
            setTimeout(ready,50);
            if (command) {
                command();
            }
            if (conf.over) {
                parent.bind("mouseenter mouseleave",evHandler);
            }

        }
    }

    function getDestination() {
        return conf.destination || target.attr("data-destination");
    }

    function ready() {
        jthis.triggerHandler("ready.pixelentity");
    }

    function loadTo(destination) {
        if (!destination || from == to) {
            return;
        }

        loading = true;

        if (typeof destination == "string") {
            to = $("<img>").attr("src",destination);
        } else {
            to = destination;
        }
        $.pixelentity.preloader.load(to,destinationLoaded);
    }

    function destinationLoaded(destination) {
        loading = false;
        to = destination[0];
        init();
        if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version >= 9) {
            setTimeout(run,50);
        } else {
            run();
        }
    }

    function init() {
        if (inited) {
            if (fallback) {
                initFallback();
            }
            return;
        }
        inited = true;

        // firefox 3.X has bugs with canvas
        if (conf.fallback || ($.browser.mozilla && $.browser.version.substr(0, 1) == '0')) {
            initFallback();
        } else {
            // detect canvas support
            output = document.createElement("canvas");

            if (output.getContext) {
                initCanvas();
            } else {
                initFallback();
            }
        }
    }

    function initCanvas() {

        initOutput();
        buffer = document.createElement("canvas");
        buffer.width = w;
        buffer.height = h;

        buffer2 = document.createElement("canvas");
        buffer2.width = w;
        buffer2.height = h;

        toBuffer = document.createElement("canvas");
        toBuffer.width = w;
        toBuffer.height = h;

        fromBuffer = document.createElement("canvas");
        fromBuffer.width = w;
        fromBuffer.height = h;

        output = output.getContext("2d");
        buffer = buffer.getContext("2d");
        toBuffer = toBuffer.getContext("2d");
        fromBuffer = fromBuffer.getContext("2d");

        items = [];

        n = parseInt(conf.elements,10);

        var min = parseInt(conf.minSize,10);
        var max = parseInt(conf.maxSize,10)-min;

        for (var i=0;i<n;i++) {
            items.push({
                x: Math.round(Math.random()*w),
                y: Math.round(Math.random()*h),
                d: Math.round(Math.random()*duration),
                r: Math.round(Math.random()*max+min)
            });
        }

    }

    function initFallback() {
        fallback = true;
        output = to;
        initOutput();
    }

    function initOutput() {
        output.width = w;
        output.height = h;

        offset = offset || target.offset();
        parent.prepend(output);

        $(output)
            .css("position","absolute")
            .css("z-index",(parseInt(target.css("z-index"),10) || 0)+1)
            .offset(offset)
            .show();

        duration = parseInt(conf.duration,10);
        compositingDuration = Math.round(1*duration/3);
    }

    function run() {
        started = $.now();
        elapsed = 0;
        $.pixelentity.ticker.unregister(worker);
        $.pixelentity.ticker.register(worker);
        transition = conf.transition;

        if (transition == "random") {
            transition = transitionTypes[Math.round(Math.random()*transitionTypes.length)];
        } else if (transition == "all") {
            transition = transitionTypes[transitionIdx++ % transitionTypes.length];
        }

        if (from instanceof jQuery) {
            if (!fallback) {
                from.hide();
            }
            from = from[0];
        } 

        if (!fallback) {
            fromBuffer.drawImage(from,0,0);
            toBuffer.drawImage(to,0,0);
        }


        worker();

    }

    function canvasWorker() {
        var ratio = 0;

        output.globalCompositeOperation = buffer.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";

        buffer.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
        buffer.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
        buffer.lineWidth = 1;

        // HERE
        if (elapsed > compositingDuration) {
            ratio = jQuery.easing.easeOutQuad(0, elapsed-compositingDuration, 0, 1, duration-compositingDuration);
            buffer.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,"+ratio+")";
            buffer.fillRect(0,0,w,h);                       
            output.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
            output.globalAlpha = 1-ratio;
            output.drawImage(fromBuffer.canvas,0,0);
        } else {
            output.globalAlpha = 1;
            output.drawImage(fromBuffer.canvas,0,0);
        }

        var x,y,r,size;
        var PI2 = Math.PI*2;
        var item;


        for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
            item = items[i];

            if (elapsed > item.d) {
                //ratio = (elapsed-item.d)/(duration-item.d);

                ratio =  jQuery.easing.easeOutQuad(0, elapsed-item.d, 0, 1, duration-item.d);

                if (ratio >= 1) {
                    continue;
                }


                buffer.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,"+ratio/2+")";
                buffer.strokeStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,"+ratio+")";

                switch (transition) {
                    case "circles":
                        buffer.beginPath();
                        buffer.arc(item.x,item.y,Math.round(item.r*ratio),0,PI2,false);
                        buffer.fill();
                        buffer.stroke();
                    break;
                    case "squares":
                        r = Math.round(item.r*ratio);
                        x = item.x-r;
                        y = item.y-r;
                        size = r << 1;
                        buffer.fillRect(x,y,size,size);
                        buffer.strokeRect(x-0.5,y-0.5,size,size);
                    break;
                    case "vertbars":
                        r = Math.round(item.r*ratio);
                        x = item.x-r;
                        size = r << 1;
                        buffer.fillRect(x,0,size,h);
                        buffer.beginPath();
                        buffer.moveTo(x+0.5,0);
                        buffer.lineTo(x+0.5,h);
                        buffer.moveTo(x+size+0.5,0);
                        buffer.lineTo(x+size+0.5,h);
                        buffer.stroke();
                    break;
                    case "horizbars":
                        r = Math.round(item.r*ratio);
                        y = item.x-r;
                        size = r << 1;
                        buffer.fillRect(0,y,w,size);
                        buffer.beginPath();
                        buffer.moveTo(0,y+0.5);
                        buffer.lineTo(w,y+0.5);
                        buffer.moveTo(0,y+size+0.5);
                        buffer.lineTo(w,y+size+0.5);
                        buffer.stroke();
                    break;
                }



            }
        }

        if (conf.boost > 0) {
            ratio =  jQuery.easing.easeOutQuad(0, elapsed-compositingDuration, 0, 1, duration-compositingDuration);
            output.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
            output.globalAlpha = conf.boost*(1-ratio);
            output.drawImage(buffer.canvas,0,0);
        }

        buffer.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";
        buffer.globalAlpha = 1;
        buffer.drawImage(toBuffer.canvas,0,0);

        output.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
        output.globalAlpha = 1;
        output.drawImage(buffer.canvas,0,0);

    }

    function fallbackWorker() {
        ratio = jQuery.easing.easeOutQuad(0, elapsed, 0, 1, duration);
        $(output).css("opacity",ratio);
    }

    function worker() {
        var item;

        elapsed = $.now()-started;

        if (elapsed > duration) {
            elapsed = duration;
        } 

        if (fallback) {
            fallbackWorker();
        } else {
            canvasWorker();
        }

        if (elapsed == duration) {
            $.pixelentity.ticker.unregister(worker);                
            reset();

            if (conf.slideshow) {
                var idx = (slideshowIndex-1) % images.length;
                var evParams = {"idx":idx};
                target.triggerHandler("change.pixelentity",evParams);
                jthis.triggerHandler("change.pixelentity",evParams);
                if (conf.links && conf.linkTarget) {
                    conf.linkTarget.attr("href",conf.links[idx]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function reset() {
        var tmp;

        if (fallback) {
            tmp = $(from).attr("style");
            $(to).attr("style",tmp).show();
            $(from).replaceWith(to[0]);
        } 
        tmp = from;
        from = to;
        to = tmp;
        started = 0;
        if (command) {
            command();
            command = false;
        }
    }

    function swap() {
        active = !active;
        loadTo(to);
    }

    function execute(cb) {
        if (loading || started !== 0) {
            command = cb;
        } else {
            cb();
        }
    }

    function slideshow() {
        execute(function() {
            loadTo(images[slideshowIndex++ % images.length]);
        });
    }

    function evHandler(e) {
        if (conf.slideshow) {
            if (e.type == "mouseenter") {
                if (!slideshowTimer) {
                    slideshow();
                    slideshowTimer = setInterval(slideshow,Math.max(conf.duration+200,conf.delay));
                }
            } else {
                clearInterval(slideshowTimer);
                slideshowTimer = 0;
                slideshowIndex = 0;
                slideshow();
            }
        } else if (!firstRun) {
            mouseOver = e.type == "mouseenter";
            if (mouseOver != active) {
                execute(swap);
            }

        } else {
            mouseOver = true;
            firstRun = false;
            active = true;
            loadTo(getDestination());
        }
    }

    $.extend(self, {
        bind: function(ev,handler) {
            jthis.bind(ev,handler);
        },
        load: function(destination) {
            execute(function () {
                loadTo(destination);
            });
        },
        reverse: function() {
            execute(swap);
        },
        destroy: function() {
            clearInterval(slideshowTimer);
            $.pixelentity.ticker.unregister(worker);
            if (conf.over) {
                parent.unbind("mouseenter mouseleave",evHandler);
            }
            if (jthis) {
                jthis.remove();
            }
            if (output) {
                $(output).remove();
            }
            jthis = self = undefined;
            target.data("peTransitionHilight", null);
            target = undefined;
        }
    });

    start();


}

// jQuery plugin implementation
$.fn.peTransitionHilight = function(conf) {
    // return existing instance

    var api = this.data("peTransitionHilight");

    if (api) { 
        return api; 
    }

    conf = $.extend(true, {}, $.pixelentity.hilight.conf, conf);

    // install peScrollThumb for each entry in jQuery object
    this.each(function() {
        api = new PeTransitionHilight($(this), conf);
        $(this).data("peTransitionHilight", api); 
    });

    return conf.api ? api: this;         
};


})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends completely on the API to your particular slider. If they haven't given you a [hook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking) to control the slider, then anything you do will be a hack.

Judging by the command you're using, I'd guess you're using pixelentity's “Transition Effect” and if the documentation I found [here](http://alcobendasfutsal.org/docs/transition_help_file.html) is anything to go by, you might be able to call

```
$('#headerwrapper img').peTransitionHilight({
  slideshow: false          
});
```

But then again, I don't see much to suggest that this will actually work for starting and stopping this effect. Sliders are a dime a dozen and I would suggest using something which is

1. Free
2. Open Source
3. Better documented
4. Created in a more "standard" way (`data-destination` is an "odd" structure).

Using just about any of [these sliders from UnHeap.com](http://www.unheap.com/section/sliders-carousels/) would put you in a better position to customize behaviour.

Comment: I forgot to paste the plugin's code, but it's there now. Yes, I tried setting it to false when clicking a button but that wouldn't stop it. As for finding a different plugin, most of them are all the same, i.e., lame, unoriginal.

Comment: As much as I love reading through hundreds of lines of someone's crappy jquery plugin, in the future, a link to documentation might be a better thing to include ;)
As for for sliders being "lame and unoriginal", there are only 3 things which distinguish sliders: transitions, chrome, and code. Spoiler, all sliders suck.
Without any reason to believe that this plugin can be stopped and started on command I would suggest destroying and recreating it.